# AEM: Issue using Command Line DAM Workflow

Tags: aem

I like to execute a command line programm as a DAM workflow. I tried to implement the ImageMagic example from here: [Best Practices for Configuring ImageMagick](https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/6-2/assets/using/best-practices-for-imagemagick.html):

I addded a new Workflow Model,

added "command line" from the "DAM Workflow" list.

In the Argument tab set Mime type to "image/jpeg" (even tried wihtout Mime type)

and in Commands: `"C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-7.0.7-Q16\magick.exe" convert ${file} -flip ${file}-flipped.jpg` (instead of `magick convet ...` because in another discussion using an absolute path instead of global name helped people [Re: CommmandLineProcess : ImageMagick](https://forums.adobe.com/message/9577694#thread-post-9577680))

I then added a luncher. And uploaded an Image to the DAM.
In the workflow > instances overview, i see that the workflow was started, it's running and the command line job is set to active.

Unfortunantly this state is never chnaged and no new asset is generated via imageMagic.
I even tried replacing the command with something simple like "ren C:\test\foo.txt bar.txt" which renames a local file. The chnage never happend either.

My question is what am i doing wrong, and how can i debug / find the command outputs? in \crx-quickstart\logs i couldn't find any logs regarding CommandLineProcess.

Thanx

Comment: Any errors in the `error.log`?

Comment: In IM 7, you should use magick without the convert. So this should be the correct syntax: `"C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-7.0.7-Q16\magick.exe" ${file} -flip ${file}-flipped.jpg`. Sorry I do not know DAM

Comment: @Jens, i don't get any new entries in the error.log when i upload an image.

Comment: @fmw42 thanx for the hint. i corrected that. but unfortunantly still not working.

Comment: Make sure ImageMagick is working in command line mode and has appropriate delegates. See what you get from `magick.exe -version`. If that is working fine, then try `magick.exe logo: logo.gif`. If that works, then it must not be an ImageMagick problem. Sorry I do not know DAM.

Comment: it works when i run the command directly in command line. e.g. `"C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-7.0.7-Q16\magick.exe" path\to\img.jpg -flip path\to\img-flipped.jpg`

Comment: Did you maybe start AEM by double clicking? On OSX at least this gives AEM a pretty empty PATH, could be similar on Windows. Try starting it from the command line so it inherits the same environment variables you get when imagemagick works for you on the cli.